# JSF web application to monitor client resources

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications

I have to provide a way in which a server will monitor its client's resources (i.e. cpu usage and ram) and store the data in a database.

I am learning about the JSF right now and aim to develop a web application that will use OperatingSystemMXBean methods on the client to get the resources of that machine. The problem is that I am not sure if this is the right approach to the task or even possible to do it with the JSF - operatingSystemMXBean combo.

My question - is it possible to do it this way? And if yes, is this approach worth the effort or is there a far simpler way of doing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run java code on the client side. As you are new to JSF you should read more about this technology. The java codes that you write in jsf pages compile in the server side and the result will pass to client browser. If you want to get client resources like ram and cpu you need third party apps on the client side. Maybe there were some plugins that installs on client browser to do this(or you write your own) that you should search more about this. And also another approach is that you write a program which installs in the client pc to send his resources information to your server over internet.

Comment: Depends on what the 'client' is. If this is a remote server, sure you can run java on them. Maybe OP effectively wants a client -> server -> remote-server system. Not really clear from the question (but your assumption is not strange)

Comment: @Kukeltje the title of OP question is JSF web application to monitor client resources

Comment: Yes, but in more than 50% of the questions here where people do not seem to fully understand web development or have a sort of not common requirement, the title is not matching with what they actually mean. But like I added, you assumption is not strange, I would assume the same. But since the question is not that logical (why would you monitor client resources with a web application that needs to run in a browser? If it is closed on the client, you have no information), I sort of assume nothing ;-)

Comment: So there is no way in which you can run Java code on the client with JSF. I will have to write an application for the client side which will pass information to the server.

Comment: You can't run java on the client period... Totally independent of JSF. You used to be able to run applets but all this was plain html/browser related nothing server-side technology. Still your usecase is weird. I think you might have an http://xyproblem.info